# theme is not showing in admin panel list magento2

Tags: magento2, theme, custom

i just create new test theme but it is not showing in admin panel theme list

`app/design/frontend/Magento/mytheme/theme.xml`

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
     <title>My theme</title> <!-- your theme's name -->
     <parent>Magento/blank</parent> <!-- the parent theme, in case your theme inherits from an existing theme -->
     <media>
         <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image> <!-- the path to your theme's preview image -->
     </media>
 </theme>
```

Comment: I have similar issue. The only difference, I created my new blank theme with a different Vendor name than "Magento". Is that allowed? So my structure is:
```app/code/design/mycompany/mynewtheme/``` I just cannot make it work - in admin panel there's only Luma and Magento blank default themes, there's no new theme I created.

Comment: did you deploy the `content` and check `pub/static` folder . i will be great if you post new question with your code it is more helpful to give solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

figure out by myself. i was missing the

`app/design/frontend/Magento/mytheme/composer.json`

```
{
    "name": "magento/theme-frontend-blank",
    "description": "N/A",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
        "magento/theme-frontend-blank": "100.0.*",
        "magento/framework": "100.0.*"
    },
    "type": "magento2-theme",
    "version": "100.0.1",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

`app/design/frontend/Magento/mytheme/registration.php`

```
<?php
/**
* Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/Magento/mytheme',
    __DIR__
);
```

[Reference](http://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-create-simple-theme/)

Answer (score 8):

In my case, it worked after I ran the following command from the Magento 2 root folder:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

If it doesn't work, then you may run the command with `sudo`:

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Answer (score 6):

Follow steps for create new theme:

step : 1 (theme.xml inside app/design/frontend/Magento/companyname)

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Magento Companyname</title>
    <parent>Magento/luma</parent>
    <media>
        <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image>
    </media>
</theme>
```

Step : 2 (registration.php inside app/design/frontend/Magento/companyname)

In this file, ***we must use companyname in small case*** for defined value of our theme frontend/Magento/**companyname**.

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/Magento/companyname',
    __DIR__
);
```

Step : 3 composer.json (composer.json inside app/design/frontend/Magento/companyname)

```
{
    "name": "magento/theme-frontend-companyname",
    "description": "N/A",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
        "magento/theme-frontend-luma": "100.0.*",
        "magento/framework": "100.0.*"
    },
    "type": "magento2-theme",
    "version": "100.0.2",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I had similar issues with my custom theme not showing in Magento 2.1.6, however, it seems that my files were correct as per the instructions found on Magento Dev Docs - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

My issue may have been due to the mode being set to production rather than developer due to speed issues running on localhost.

I found that the theme wouldn't show however until I had run the following in shell...

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento setup:upgrade 
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: maybe you didn't set the developer mode .

Comment: @QaisarSatti this is true, I was running in production mode due to slow issues on localhost.

Comment: you must mention **production mode** in your answer too

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I accidentially created **registration.xml** instead of **registration.php**

Answer (score 0):

Follow bellow steps

step : 1 (theme.xml)

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Magento Apple</title>
    <parent>Magento/luma</parent>
    <media>
        <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image>
    </media>
</theme>
```

Step : 2 (registration.php)

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/Magento/Apple',
    __DIR__
);
```

Step : 3 composer.json

```
{
    "name": "magento/theme-frontend-apple",
    "description": "N/A",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
        "magento/theme-frontend-luma": "100.0.*",
        "magento/framework": "100.0.*"
    },
    "type": "magento2-theme",
    "version": "100.0.2",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

[More Details](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html)

Comment: I have followed these steps and it worked, however, I needed to change theme.xml file in order to change the title and add a parent theme, however, change is not refreshed. I have the cache disabled, so I don't know what else to try.