# Suggest me Magento2 Theme development best tutorial

Tags: magento2, theme

Please help me by suggesting a best tutorial for developing a theme in magento2.

I am searching on google for many hours but not find any decent one for this.
Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Have you tried it http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/bk-frontend-dev-guide.html ?

Comment: Can you tell me that is there any way to change header totally. Like if i give you example that in 1.9 we can change the total header only in header.phtml. But i can not find something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[found one video on youtube very useful](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2-zwsohmGsE)

[one useful tutorial on module development](http://www.venustheme.com/how-to-create-magento-2-module/)

check this also you will get good idea about magento theme development.

http://inchoo.net/magento-2/frontend-theme-architecture/

Comment: Can you tell me that is there any way to change header totally. Like if i give you example that in 1.9 we can change the total header only in header.phtml. But i can not find something like that.

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_columns.

Comment: In this link you can get a lot of information about layout and changing header and all the things.

Answer (score 1):

i will suggest magento frontend developer guide

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-general.html

also helpful

http://blog.magestore.com/how-to-create-custom-theme-on-magento-2-part-1/

also check

[theme is not showing in admin panel list magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94541/theme-is-not-showing-in-admin-panel-list-magento2)

Comment: Can you tell me that is there any way to change header totally. Like if i give you example that in 1.9 we can change the total header only in header.phtml. But i can not find something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can find it in Magento devdocs itself.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

Other tutorials may also help

http://blog.magestore.com/how-to-create-custom-theme-on-magento-2-part-1/

http://blog.belvg.com/creating-and-managing-themes-in-magento-2-0.html

Answer (score 0):

i can suggest you some links that im finding Magento information too, check it pls:
1. [http://devdocs.magento.com/]
2. [http://www.magesolution.com/blog/]
Hope my suggest help you more!